# how to design a web application that developers can use to retrieve the crashdump/Logs from customer environment

Tags: java, http, web

Hi  I am c++ developer and my knowledge to web technologies is minimum. Right now i am trying to design a web application which the development team can use to connect to specific customer and collect any crash dumps or log files.

With my research i realized it could be the following way.

1) develop an agent with build it http server and listing for request in specific port and install it in a machine with internet access and public ip address in all customer sites environment.

2) The agent is capable of collecting the required information from the customer environment based on the request it receives.

3) Develop an application with browser interface, and installed it centrally on the development data center. This application must have capability to connect to a specific customer environment and send http request over the internet to listening agent in that customer site and collect crash dump or logs or some statistics on the customer environment based on the request.

I am not sure this is the right way of doing, but I am sure there is a better way to do it. 
Any help or pointers on what is the right approach and what kind of infrastructure is require to implement this kind of a service is highly appreciated.

Regards,
Prakash R

Answer (score 0):

The approach looks serviceable, except you don't need to develop any applications to do that, as existing applications fit the bill nicely:

1. Use a web server of your choice. Apache is well known and open source (free). You might wish to configure security.
2. Assuming you're running under unix, you could use a link to include the log directory in the file system the apache serves.
3. Use your browser. (You obviously have one already). If you have many sites, you could use bookmarks, on a link list in your intranet, or ...